# Are there any ways to save MKPlacemark instances to Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm a new iOS developer.

I'd like to save MKPlacemark instances to Realm, but I don't know how to save it. To save in Realm, all properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject.

So in this case, how can I convert MKPlacemark into appropriate properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Realm objects only supports primitive types and references to other Realm objects, you'll need to create a mechanism that can translate the components of `MKPlacemark` to Realm and back again.

Probably the cleanest way would be to have a public variable named `mkPlacemark` (following the Swift 3 naming conventions of Objective-C objects as properties like `cgImage` :) ) that upon setting or getting, will perform the conversion internally.

```
class Placemark: Object {
   dynamic var latitude = 0.0
   dynamic var longitude = 0.0
   dynamic var street: String?
   dynamic var city: String?
   dynamic var zipCode: String?
   dynamic var country: String?

   public var mkPlacemark: MKPlacemark {
      set {
         latitude = newValue.coordinate.latitude
         longitude = newValue.coordinate.longitude
         street = newValue.addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStreetKey]
         city = newValue.addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressCityKey]
         zipCode = newValue.addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressZipCodeKey]
         country = newValue.addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressCountryKey]
      }
      get {
         let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
         let addressDictionary = [kABPersonAddressStreetKey: street,
                                  kABPersonAddressCityKey: city,
                                  kABPersonAddressZipCodeKey: zipCode,
                                  kABPersonAddressCountryKey: country]
         return MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)
      }
   }

   convinience init(placemark: MKPlacemark) {
      super.init()
      self.mkPlacemark = placemark
   }

}
```

*(I wrote this code by hand, so it might need some tweaking before it can actually be compiled. :) )*

Comment: Thanks a lot TiM. Your approach is great & yeah, it needs some tweaking. So I've added an answer with working code.

Comment: I checked this answer, but all the answers were really helpful for me :-)
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own RLMObject contains MKPlacemark properties.

```
class RLMPlacemark: Object {
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var addressDictionary: [String: Any]?

required convenience init?(placemark: MKPlacemark) {
    self.init()
    self.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
    self.addressDictionary = placemark.addressDictionary as! [String : Any]?
}
```

}

Comment: You cannot directly store a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` property in Realm. You have to break it up into two `Doubles` (latitude and longitude).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is the tweaked version of TiM's answer. The following properties are subjected to change:

`RLMObject` can't have `MKPlacemark`property type. so mkPlacemark can't have `set`. It can have `get` & it acts as instance variable without being a stored property. Updated for iOS 9+; Use new Contacts framework. `super.init()` have to changed to `self.init()`

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import RealmSwift
import Contacts

class RLMPlacemark: Object {
    dynamic var latitude = 0.0
    dynamic var longitude = 0.0
    dynamic var street: String?
    dynamic var city: String?
    dynamic var state: String?
    dynamic var zipCode: String?
    dynamic var country: String?
    dynamic var countryCode: String?

    public var placemark: MKPlacemark {
        get {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let addressDictionary = [CNPostalAddressStreetKey : street,
                                     CNPostalAddressCityKey : city,
                                     CNPostalAddressStateKey : state,
                                     CNPostalAddressPostalCodeKey : zipCode,
                                     CNPostalAddressCountryKey : country,
                                     CNPostalAddressISOCountryCodeKey : countryCode]
            let warningFreeAddressDictionary = (addressDictionary as Any) as? [String : Any]
            return MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: warningFreeAddressDictionary)
        }
    }

    convenience init(lat: Double, long: Double, street: String?, city: String?, state: String?, zipCode: String?, country: String?, countryCode:String?) {
        self.init()
        self.latitude = lat
        self.longitude = long
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipCode = zipCode
        self.country = country
        self.countryCode = countryCode
    }

    convenience init(placemark: MKPlacemark) {
        self.init(lat: placemark.coordinate.latitude,
                  long: placemark.coordinate.longitude,
                  street: placemark.addressDictionary?[CNPostalAddressStreetKey] as? String,
                  city: placemark.addressDictionary?[CNPostalAddressCityKey] as? String,
                  state: placemark.addressDictionary?[CNPostalAddressStateKey] as? String,
                  zipCode: placemark.addressDictionary?[CNPostalAddressPostalCodeKey] as? String,
                  country: placemark.addressDictionary?[CNPostalAddressCountryKey] as? String,
                  countryCode: placemark.addressDictionary?[CNPostalAddressISOCountryCodeKey] as? String)
    }
}
```

It would be great if this helps anyone. The casting of `AddressDictionary` is redundant. you can use it directly but it throws a warning message & I hate warning. ;)

Comment: Realm can have other property types, so long as they’re marked as ignored in which case they won’t actually be persisted in Realm. In this case, because the propert wasn’t marked dynamic, it won’t be visible to the Objective-C runtime (hence it’ll be ignored). This way it’s possible to have additional properties that map to Realm backed data, but won’t be saved.